# Crystallography: relationship between side length and radius of atom

Tags: crystals

For a FCC the relationship between the radius and the side length 'a' is

4r=(2)^.5 a

And this is derived by drawing a diagonal across one of the faces of the unit cell.

However, is this meant to be an approximation?

What troubles me is why is this diagonal the one that is representative of the relationship between the radius and the sides? Is this the same relationship that exists if I drew, instead of a diagonal, just a line across one side of the unit cell? I think it is not because that would yield an equation like so:

2r+x=a ; where x is the chunk of the side that is left out.

So why is this diagonal the representative one?

Thanks.

Comment: The choice is arbitrary but we invariably use the diagonal line that you refer to because it is the *simplest* choice.

Comment: BUt it's an approximation right? Like, this relationship doesn't hold if we consider a side of the unit cell, or does it? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the spheres are as large as possible (i.e. they're 'kissing') then the relationship between $r$ and $a$ is exact. Of course though, atoms don't have well-defined radii, so $r$ is only a useful approximation of the atomic radius.

Comment: @lemon The atomic radius was determined by x-ray diffraction. It is derived from the mean of the distance between atoms, so the fuzziness determining the radius is minimized.

Comment: @lemon I can see how a diagonal holds the relationship I mentioned. But why is it the case that one side of the unit cell will also have to hold this relationship? thanks.

Comment: @David Why *wouldn't* the 'side' also obey that relationship? It's the same cell (and therefore the same $a$) and the spheres have the same radius $r$. I can't figure what difficulty you're having...